# Can i merge these two classes via specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Here is a class i wrote to mock .NET properties. It appears to do what i want. However instead of using Property1 and Property2 can i write Property and have it figure out which of the two classes i want?

```
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
class Property{
protected:
    Property(const Property&p) {}
    Property() {}
public:
    virtual Property& operator=(const Property& src)=0;
    virtual Property& operator=(const T& src)=0;
    virtual operator T() const=0;
};

template <class T>
class Property1 : public Property<T> {
    T v;
public:
    Property1(const Property1&p) {*this=static_cast<T>(p);}
    //Property1() { printf("ctor %X\n", this);}
    Property1(){}
    Property& operator=(const Property& src) { return*this=static_cast<T>(src); }
    Property& operator=(const T& src) {
        printf("write %X\n", this);
        v = src; 
        return *this; 
    }
    operator T() const {
        printf("Read %X\n", this);
        return v;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Property2 : public Property<T> {
    typedef T(*Gfn)();
    typedef void(*Sfn)(T);
    Gfn gfn;
    Sfn sfn;
public:
    Property2(const Property2&p) {*this=static_cast<T>(p);}
    //Property2() { printf("ctor %X\n", this);}
    Property2(Gfn gfn_, Sfn sfn_):gfn(gfn_), sfn(sfn_) {}
    Property& operator=(const Property& src) { return*this=static_cast<T>(src); }
    Property& operator=(const T& src) {
        printf("write %X\n", this);
        sfn(src);
        return *this; 
    }
    operator T() const {
        printf("Read %X\n", this);
        return gfn();
    }
};

void set(int v) {}
int get() {return 9;}

Property1<int> a, b;
Property2<int> c(get,set), d(get,set);
void fn(Property<int>& v) { v=v=31; }
int main(){
    a=b=5;
    c=d=11;
    a=c=b=d=15;
    fn(a);
    fn(c);
}
```

Comment: Good luck in getting the compiler to guess what you wanted...

Answer (score 2):

You could make `Property` hold and operate on an implementation, let `Property1` and `Property2` be two such implementations, and determine which of the two to create by `Property`'s ctor:

```
template<typename T>
class PropertyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~PropertyInterface() {}
    virtual T get() const = 0;
    virtual void set(const T&) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Property1 : public PropertyInterface<T> {
    T v;
public:
    T get() { return v; }
    void set(const T& value) { v = value; }
};

template<typename T>
class Property2 : public PropertyInterface<T> {
    Gfn g;
    Sfn s;
public:
    Property2(Gfn getter, Sfn setter) : g(getter), s(setter) {}

    T get() { return g(); }
    void set(const T& v) { set(v); }
};

template<typename T>
class Property {
    PropertyInterface<T> impl;
public:
    Property() : impl(new Property1()) {}
    Property(const T& v) : impl(new Property1()) { impl->set(v); }
    Property(Gfn getter, Sfn setter) : impl(new Property2(getter, setter)) {}
    Property(const Property& p) : impl(new Property1()) { impl->set(p.impl->get()); }
    // ...more ctors...

    ~Property() { delete impl; }

    Property& operator=(const Property&) { impl->set(p.impl->get()); return *this; }
    Property& operator=(const T& v) { impl->set(v); return *this; }

    operator T() const { return impl->get(); }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what a factory is supposed to do?

The factory method can be put as well in the property class. I prefer to create a extra factory class to make clear that it is a use of the factory pattern.

**Edit: Added overload of factory method**

```
template <class T>
class Property {
};

template <class T>
class Property1 : public Property<T> {
};

template <class T>
class Property2 : public Property<T> {
public:
    typedef T(*Gfn)();
    typedef void(*Sfn)(T);
    Property2(Gfn, Sfn) {}

};

class PropertyFactory {
public:
    template<class T>
    static Property<T>* InstanciateProperty() {
        return new Property1<T>();
    }
    template<class T>
    static Property<T>* InstanciateProperty(typename Property2<T>::Gfn gfn, typename Property2<T>::Sfn sfn) {
        return new Property2<T>(gfn, sfn);
    }
};

void set(int){}
int get() { return 0; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Property<int>* prop(PropertyFactory::InstanciateProperty<int>());
    Property<int>* prop1(PropertyFactory::InstanciateProperty<int>(&get, &set));
    delete prop;
    delete prop1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to downvote but i changed my mind. Your answer does not show how i can get either class based on what i pass as a constructor. I believe the other answer does but i'm still reading it

Comment: It is a sketch. Perhaps you want to read about the factory pattern. In the factory Method InstanciateProperty you could decide what type you want to instanciate. The commented if and ifdef in this function shows where you could decide what class to use. If you want  to decide the type to instanciate on the parameters given - you could add a overload.